# Intellij can't find java.net.http when compiling with Java 11

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-11

I'm trying to get one of my projects ready for Java 11 but for some reason Intellij can't find [`java.net.http`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk11/docs/api/java.net.http/module-summary.html). It isn't underlining it as not found in `module-info.java` like it would if I typed it wrong but when I try build the project I get the error below. I've tried reinstalling Intellij 2018.2.3 and uninstalling all other versions of Java. Any advice on how to get this working would be appreciated.

Error:

```
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'crawler'
Information:javac 11 was used to compile java sources
Information:15/09/2018 11:16 - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 636 ms
C:\Users\Will\IdeaProjects\crawler\src\module-info.java
Error:(2, 22) java: module not found: java.net.http
```

module-info.java:

```
module crawler {
    requires java.net.http;
}
```

Request.java:

```
package Request;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;

public class Request {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("starting download");
        String body = HttpClient.newBuilder().build().send(HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create("https://example.com")).build(), HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString()).body();
        System.out.println("finished download:" + body);
    }
}
```

Structure:

```
crawler
    src
        Request
            Request.java
        module-info.java
```

Comment: Can't reproduce, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @CrazyCoder added

Comment: @Will there is no `main/java` inside your src folder?

Comment: @Will [Builds and runs without issues](https://i.imgur.com/PL1nRdo.png) in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.3 for me. What Java 11 build do you use? What are module/project language level settings?

Comment: This comment is not apropos to your problem, but your chosen package name is wrong: 1) the name should be all lowercase, 2) the name should follow the domain name convention; see https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.2-specific-identifier-names

Comment: @CrazyCoder I just installed Java 11 build 26 and IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.3 in a clean VirtualBox instance of Windows 10 and it builds for me. Could it in some way be a Windows issue since I had Java 8-11 installed until today? I'm using Java 11 build 26 and project language level 9.

Comment: Ahhhhh I see. I'm dumb. The project language level obviously needs to be 11... Sorry for wasting your time!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the wrong project language level set. To use [`java.net.http`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk11/docs/api/java.net.http/module-summary.html) you need it to be at least 11. To change the project language level see: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-page.html

Hopefully this helps someone else out.

Comment: I'm using build #IU-192.5728.96 and this, unfortunately does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 38):

In the case that the above proposed resolution (by @Will) does not solve your issue as was the case with me (i.e. *setting the project language level*), check to to see what the **bytecode target version** of your java compiler has been set to, in your project preferences:
[image: Set project preferences byte code version for java in IntelliJ]

Comment: It worked after restarting Intellij Idea 2020.1 (on windows)

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem with the package jdk.jfr.
This is how I fixed it. It should work for you too.

In order to make it work I had to make 2 changes:

First I had to set the language level to 11; see in the picture below.

[image]

Then I had to adjust the Java Compiler. The Target bytecode version is 11 and I set the project bytecode version *Same as language level*. Then you don't have to change all of them constantly. Please see picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For those who are having this problem in 2022, even if the solutions mentioned here did not help, I was able to figure out what the problem was and how to fix this.

First of all I wanted to make sure that the problem is not from my Maven config, so I ran the following in my *terminal*:

```
mvn package
```

followed by:

```
java -cp target/covid-cases-cli-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.matrixeternal.covidcasescli.App
```

and it was build without any errors whatsoever. So it means something is up with IntelliJ.

I am using Java 17 and building with Maven using IntelliJ. IntelliJ uses its own internal command to build the project. To override this behaviour, you must go to `Preferences - Build, Execution & Deployment - Build Tools - Maven - Runner` and select the option `Delegate IDE build/run actions to maven` which will essentially run directly from the Maven config file using the mvn tool installed in the system, instead of using the IDE command.

[image: Delegate IDE build/run actions to maven option]

Answer (score 0):

Set the compiler for IntelliJ as Java 11
IntelliJ Idea-> Preferences-> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Java Compiler
Select java 11 from the drop down